# Installing numpy on mac osx (snow leopard)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to install numpy on my mac machine.
Whatever I try, I end up getting this error when trying to run my python code

```
 import numpy as np
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx-    
10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
 import add_newdocs
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx- 
10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx-
10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from type_check import *
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx-
10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx-
10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-
macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCapsule_Import
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so
Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-2.0.0.dev_26aa3cf_20110808-py2.7-macosx-
 10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

Also when I enter Python in my terminal it takes me to python 2.6.1 version.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [macports](http://www.macports.org/) or [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) as a package system.

With macports, installing numpy is as easy as

```
cd /opt/local/bin 
sudo ./port install py27-numpy
```

where py27 may be replaced with your favorite python version.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the paths in the error message, it looks like you intended to install Numpy for a Python 2.7 that you've already installed. You're getting Python 2.6 instead. This suggests a problem with your `PATH` environment variable. Adjust the `PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` so that the executables for the Python 2.7 appear before the system versions in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fairly complete scientific python environment on your Mac I would recommend the EPD free Python distribution. That will give you numpy and scipy among others.